# Rails: json response from secure action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, devise

Originally I had quite usual ajax form with json response:

```
def create
  # created logic omitted as most likely irrelevant
  render :json => {:success => true} #over simplified JSON for debug purposes
end
```

So far so good, works as expected.  I've added security on the create action via [ssl_requirement](https://github.com/rails/ssl_requirement/) gem:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  ssl_required :create
  # rest of the code omitted, 'create' action as above
end
```

All of a sudden I get the following in my form response (observing in HttpFox):

```
Error loading content (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED)
```

The create action runs as expected (enforces HTTPS, creates an object but... fails in the browser.  To be specific, fails in **Firefox** (works on chrome).  Any clues and ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I believe your problem has to do with cross-site AJAX requests.

The fact that you are using a different protocol is making firefox believe you are making a cross-site request. Chrome, I believe, is less strict with this restriction when on local. Try visiting the site itself over `https` and see if the AJAX request goes through.

Comment: Yes, I think this is exactly what's happening.  But what are my options is given situation?

Comment: using JSONP would let you circumvent the same-origin policy. Check out this [slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/SlexAxton/breaking-the-cross-domain-barrier).